# Is there an adjective that means in a state of emergency?

Tags: adjectives

I am trying to describe a corpus of data as either working to address an emergency or enabling systemic support of continuous improvement.  So data is either systemic or "emergencyent":-)

Comment: "emergency" is a perfectly good adjective.  "Grab the emergency kit", "Use the emergency backup", "Reboot with the emergency data set".

Comment: @John Feltz  Or 'emergency' is often used as a noun modifier. I'm with the dictionaries classifying this usage as _not_ that of an adjectiive. // However the juries find on this, the word isn't used for OP's first question (communities in a state of emergency are not called emergency communities).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Understood.  But I think OP is asking about the thing (corpus of data) that *supports operations* in the case of an emergency.  Compare to "emergency command post" - it's a thing that supports operations in the event of an emergency.  But the command post itself is just fine.

Comment: I've close-voted on 'I can't decide what you require' grounds, as I think the title question and specimen sentence don't match.

Answer (score 1):

use **"urgent"**

> - adjective -  "compelling immediate action or attention; pressing, conveying a sense of pressing importance: an urgent message. [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/urgent)

Answer (score 0):

**Emergent** has a sense meaning coming up suddenly as well as other senses of the word. Indeed, according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emergent) it is the first sense of the four senses of the word:

> 1a :  arising unexpectedly b :  calling for prompt action :  urgent